# Access violation thrown when trying to send packet with a double pointer of structs to client. c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, client-server, access-violation

A client process is getting an "Access violation reading location 0x00000004" error when trying to access data from a packet that was sent from a server.

The packet is accepted just fine and handled accordingly. But I am getting the error when I try and access an double pointer that is within the packet.

Here is said pointer:

```
CGameObject **playerListImage;
```

Here is where the error is thrown:

```
void CObjectManager::SetPlayerList(CGameObject **updatedList)
{
  for(int i=0; i < m_nPlayerCount; i++)
      m_pPlayerList[i] = updatedList[i];
}
```

I know there isn't a whole lot to go off of, but here is basic summary.

A server sends me a packet. 
I handle the packet accordingly. And all data in the packet is fine, except for the double pointer.

HOWEVER I do have a client thread running on the same process as the server thread, and that client never has any trouble with the double pointer.

I'm assuming the problem has something to do with being on separate processes. But I am at a loss.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you might want to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29

Comment: could also be interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the problem is that you are trying to send a pointer 'over the wire'. You can't do that, a pointer in one process is not valid in another process.

Since it looks like you are sending a list of players. I don't think you have any choice but to send each player separately, rather than trying to send a pointer to all the players.

Comment: Ah, i assumed it was something like this. However I had no luck finding anything on it. I will move the data directly then. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to look at serialization libraries. These will help with this kind of problem. boost has one I know, I'm sure there are others.